# Build module to use it in environment without modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, es6-modules, rollup

Our application uses TypeScript's namespaces and do not use any kind of modules. We want to use [`react-datepicker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker), which is written using modules.

For example, it contains the next code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import onClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Manager, Popper, Target } from 'react-popper';
...
export default DatePicker;
```

Or transpiled:

```
var React = _interopDefault(require('react'));
var PropTypes = _interopDefault(require('prop-types'));
var classnames = _interopDefault(require('classnames'));
var onClickOutside = _interopDefault(require('react-onclickoutside'));
var moment = _interopDefault(require('moment'));
var reactPopper = require('react-popper');
...
exports['default'] = DatePicker;
```

It is required to build some js-bundle for this package, that will contain `react-datepicker` itself as global variable `DatePicker`, and all its dependecies, besides `react`, `moment`, `classnames`.

These libraries are already added to the application as global variables (`React`, `moment`, `classNames`), so it should use these global variables.

Is there some plugins and techniques for `rollup`, `webpack`, etc. that can help to build such bundle?

Comment: I went through the source and docs  of [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) and it seems to have been designed to work in react views, so I do not believe it is going to work if tour project is not react based. I don't think you can use a standalaone build that works without react

Comment: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/package.json#L88 has react as peer dependency, it is required.

Comment: @OsvaldoMaria react already exists in application as global variable. It loaded via umd react bundle. We need to build datepicker to use that global react version.

Comment: Yes, rollup and webpack are exactly made to build such a bundle. Have you tried using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with rollup, you would need to use its external and globals option like this:

```
external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'moment', 'classnames'],
globals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'classnames': 'classNames',
    'moment': 'moment'
},
```

Depending on the source file you're using, you might need to use these 2 plugins:

```
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
```

Also, you might need to use `rollup-plugin-replace` because react-datepicker seems to include `process.env.NODE_ENV` in its code, and you will need to remove that.

In case you would like to see a full working example, check this repo I created:
https://github.com/mxcoder/rollup-iife-react-datepicker

Comment: Great! Thanks you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful.